# What does KSP mean?

Tags: keyboard

I have a Yamaha PSR-540. There are a few voices on it with another voice's name and KSP in their names:

- GrndPianoKSP
- BritePnoKSP
- ElecGrPnoKSP
- HonkytonkKSP
- El.Piano1KSP
- El.Piano2KSP
- Harpsi.KSP
- Clavi.KSP
- Vibes KSP
- Marimba KSP

To me, they sound like they are duplicates of the other voices. **What does KSP mean?**

Comment: *Kerbal Space Program*

Comment: Took about a minute to google KSP. Did you have a try? This only just comes within the MP&T remit, in my opinion.

Comment: @Tim `"KSP" yamaha` doesn't get anything clear and just `"KSP"` gets *Kerbal Space Program*.

Comment: @Carl Hi, may I ask what your search terms are? I really can't find this by googling (tried the above ones and `"ksp" yamaha keyboard` and couldn't find anything)

Comment: I stand corrected -- Yamaha manuals talk a lot about stereo panning functions but never mention the difference between $VOICE  and $VOICE.KSP  .  Stupid on their part.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> "KSP" means "Keyboard Stereo Panning", that means for these voices, the placement of the instrument changes in the stereo panorama, depending on the position on the keyboard. So, "low notes" come from "left", "middle notes" "from the middle" and "high notes" "from right" (viewed from the player). For the versions of the Voices WITHOUT "KSP", the position in the stereo panorama is FIXED.

<sup>–Translated from [Yamaha Europe forum post by t4chris](https://forum.yamaha-europe.com/forum/allgemeine-diskussion/keyboards/2675-xg-voices-ksp)</sup>